# Exclude regex bash script

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find the lastlogin on certain usernames.  I want to exclude anything starting with qwer* and root but keep anything with user.name

Here is what I have already, but the last part of the regex doesn't work.  Any help appreciated.

```
lastlog | egrep '[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]|[^qwer*][^root]'
```

Answer (score 7):

That regexp doesn't do what you think it does. Lets break it down:

- `[a-zA-Z]` - the `[...]` denotes a character class. What you have means: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z (and the capital versions). This captures a *single character*! That's not what you want!
- `\.` - this is a period. Needs the backslash since `.` means "any character".
- `[a-zA-Z]` - same as above.
- `|` - or sign. Either what came before, or what comes afterwards.
- `[^qwer*]` - Captures any single character that's **not** `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, or `*`.
- `[^root]` - Captures any single character that's **not** `r`, `o`, or `t`.

As you can see, that's not exactly what you were going for. Try the following:

```
lastlog | egrep -v '^(qwer|root$)' | egrep '^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$'
```

You can't have "don't match this group" operator in regexps... That's not regular. Some implementations do provide such functionality anyway, namely PCRE and Python's `re` package.

Answer (score 3):

This should do you:

```
lastlog | egrep -v '^qwer|^root$'
```

The -v option to grep gives you the non-matching lines rather than the matching ones.

And if you specifically want user names only of the form User.Name then you can add this:

```
lastlog | egrep -v '^qwer|^root$' | egrep -i '^[a-z]*\.[a-z]*'
```

Comment: to avoid matching "rootnot" you could use `^qwer|^root$` or `^(qwer|root$)`